# Road Extraction from Latitude and Longitude using Google Maps API?

Tags: latitude-longitude, google-maps-api, road

Google Maps API allows grabbing roads for individual latitude and longitude specifications (or the nearest roads if the point/s are not on a road). However, the way it requires data to be entered for each individual request makes finding a large number of roads very difficult (in my case ~17000). I was wondering if anyone knew how to automate the process to take a list of points and spit back the relevant roads (either in Google Maps or elsewhere)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). You should probably check to make sure this is a permitted use before following through on this plan. There are any number of free ways to compile road data from public sources, but the high quality sources are not inexpensive. Extracting one road is a fair use; extracting 17k features is likely "scraping".